# TypeError: Cannot read property 'getText' of undefined

Tags: css-selectors, protractor

I'm stuck on that error: **TypeError: Cannot read property 'getText' of undefined**
When I run my test in Protractor v.4.0.14
What I understand is that getText() is not able to get a text from table cell, because CSS selector is not picking it correctly or I'm using wrong method to retrieve text from the cell?!

My page **object file's code**:

```
var HomePage = function(){

    //methods
    this.clearForm = function(){
        element(by.css("#nameInput")).clear();
        element(by.css("#surnameInput")).clear();
        element(by.css("#emailInput")).clear();
        element(by.css("#phoneInput")).clear();
    };

    this.fillForm = function(name, surname, email, phone){
        element(by.css("#nameInput")).sendKeys(name);
        element(by.css("#surnameInput")).sendKeys(surname);
        element(by.css("#emailInput")).sendKeys(email);
        element(by.css("#phoneInput")).sendKeys(phone);
    };

    this.clickSave = function(){
        element(by.css("#saveBTN")).click();
    };

    this.clickSearch = function(){
        element(by.css("#searchBTN")).click();
    };

    this.getResult = function(row, column){
        element(by.css("#result > tr:nth-child("+row+") > td:nth-   child("+column+")"));
    };

    this.clickEdit = function(row){ 
        element(by.css("input.button-primary:nth-child("+row+")")).click();
    };

    this.clickRemove = function(row){
        element(by.css("input.button:nth-child("+row+")")).click();
    };

    this.clickDeleteLocalStorage = function(){
        element(by.css("#delAllBTN")).click();
    };

};
module.exports = new HomePage();
```

And here is **spec file's code**:

```
describe("Contact book", function(){

    var page = require('./page/home_page.js');

    //input data
    var name = 'Vladimir';
    var surname = 'Putin';
    var email = 'ilovekgb@ivan.ru';
    var phone = '+01 1234 567';

    beforeEach(function(){
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
        browser.get("https://ddaawwiidd.github.io/contactbook/");
    });

    it("Should be able to save new contact", function(){
        page.fillForm(name, surname, email, phone);
        page.clickSave();
    });

    it("Should be able to search for saved contact", function(){
        page.clearForm();
        page.fillForm(name, surname, email, phone);
        page.clickSearch();
        var result = page.getResult(1,1).getText(); //that's the part causing the error
        expect(result).toContain('Vladimir');
    });

    it("Should be able to edit contact details", function(){
        page.fillForm(name, surname, email, phone);
        page.clickSearch();
        page.clickEdit(1);
        page.clearForm();
        page.fillForm('Barack', 'Obama', email, phone);
        page.clickSave();
    });

    it("Should be able to remove contact", function(){
        page.fillForm('Barack','','','');
        page.clickSearch();
        page.clickRemove(1);
    });

    it("Should be able to list all saved contacts", function(){
        page.clearForm();
        page.clickSearch();
    });

    xit("Should be able to delete localStorage", function(){
        page.clickDeleteLocalStorage(); 
        expect(page.getFirstRowResult().isDisplayed()).toBe(false);
    });


 });
```

This is screenshot of HTML:
[image: HTML screenshot]

And this is **error message**:

Failures:
1) Contact book Should be able to search for saved contact
  Message:
    Failed: Cannot read property 'getText' of undefined
  Stack:
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'getText' of undefined
        at Object. (C:\Users\djankowski\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\example\contactBook_spec.js:25:35)
        at C:\Users\djankowski\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd2\index.js:94:23
        at new ManagedPromise (C:\Users\djankowski\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:1082:7)
        at controlFlowExecute (C:\Users\djankowski\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd2\index.js:80:18)
        at TaskQueue.execute_ (C:\Users\djankowski\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2913:14)
        at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (C:\Users\djankowski\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2896:21)
        at asyncRun (C:\Users\djankowski\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2820:25)
        at C:\Users\djankowski\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:639:7
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
    From: Task: Run it("Should be able to search for saved contact") in control flow
        at Object. (C:\Users\djankowski\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd2\index.js:79:14)
        at C:\Users\djankowski\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd2\index.js:16:5
        at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (C:\Users\djankowski\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:1379:14)
        at TaskQueue.execute_ (C:\Users\djankowski\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2913:14)
        at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (C:\Users\djankowski\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2896:21)
        at asyncRun (C:\Users\djankowski\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2775:27)
    From asynchronous test:
    Error
        at Suite. (C:\Users\djankowski\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\example\contactBook_spec.js:21:2)
        at Object. (C:\Users\djankowski\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\example\contactBook_spec.js:1:1)
        at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)

I'm 4 days fresh with Protractor, so it may be a stupid mistake.

Any other suggestions regarding code are welcome too.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't know Protractor, and don't know if this has anything to do with it, or just a formatting issue here on stackoverflow, but you have some faulty spaces on this line: `element(by.css("#result > tr:nth-child("+row+") > td:nth-   child("+column+")"));` ... before last child.

Comment: It must be formatting. There are no spaces in my code:
this.getResult = function(row, column){
  element(by.css("#result>tr:nth-child("+row+")>td:nth-child("+column+")"));
 };

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `getResult()` doesnt return an `elementFinder` object, hence it throws `undefined` error

You need return the `element` back. Please check below

```
this.getResult = function(row, column){
        return element(by.css("#result > tr:nth-child("+row+") > td:nth-   child("+column+")"));
    };
```

Comment: Sure .. no problem !!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @AdityaReddy's answer few points to stress on:

`getText()` returns a promise, you have resolve it to get the actual text. Basically most of the **Protractor API methods** return promises.You could also do something like this in your `spec.js`-

```
it("Should be able to search for saved contact", function(){
    page.clearForm();
    page.fillForm(name, surname, email, phone);
    page.clickSearch();

    page.getResult(1,1).getText().then(function (text) { 
    expect(text).toContain('Vladimir');
 }); 
 // or you could directly use expect which resolves the promise internally.

    expect(page.getResult(1,1).getText()).toContain('Vladimir');
});
```

Comment: I've tried that before and it didn't change anything. AdityaReddy solution worked perfectly on the other hand.

Comment: @dave Yes the above solution would certainly work as you have to return the elementFinder to your function but do understand that `getText` returns a promise and you assigned it to `result` variable and then using `expect` to resolve it.

Comment: ahh, yes, I'm not assigning it anymore to result.